# Can't find text with Capybara

Tags: rspec, css-selectors, capybara

Good morning, I'm trying to find specific text in an (Devise email) view that uses bootstrap. My capybara version is 3.6. The css selector is:

```
body > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > b
```

and the text I'd like to find at the end of all that is `"example text"`

I've tried the following:

```
click_button "Sign up"
    
#CapybaraEmail, not currently used beyond this point yet
open_email('test@example.com')

#current_email.save_and_open
    
last_email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
    
expect(last_email.to).to eq ['test@example.com']
```

This is what I've tried and failed:

```
expect(last_email).to have_css('b', text: "example text")
expect(last_email).to have_css("body > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > b", :text => "example text")
```

I assume the syntax is wrong. I also assume that, without regex, the text inside any element must be exact or it will fail, can't just be a chunk.

Basically, I just want to find some text on a page that otherwise doesn't have any elements with an id. I've gone the id route, and basically I have to manually put an id on an element on every page I want to test, but I'm done with all that now.

How to find random text in an email view?

Once I learn this I believe I will be at Capybara level 2.

Comment: The text option does substring matching by default so that’s likely not your issue  The real question is what exactly last_email is? Are us sure it’s html?

Comment: Also, provide the full test code so we can see where `last_email` is coming from and identify what gem (if any) you're using to open/process the emails, etc.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I appreciate that, ty. I've updated the question - it's the email in ActionMailer test array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`last_email` is not an HTML document, it's an object containing a lot of fields, so you can't directly use it with Capybara.  Inspect the object and see what's in it and where the actual HTML of the email is (assuming it does actually have an HTML portion, and isn't just a text email??). It's possible something along the lines of

```
expect(last_email.html_part.body.to_s).to have_css('b', text: "example text")
```

may work, although if you are using capybara-email then just use it to do this as documented in its Readme - https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/capybara-email#readme